# Unable to return closure from closure due to lifetimes in generic type rust

Tags: events, rust, types, callback, lifetime

I'm new to rust and I'm trying to rewrite library from kotlin to rust. It is callback event library. When trying to return closure from another closure it breaks `on_event` function that registries callbacks and also breaks the invoker function which gets the invoker function due to lifetimes in the generic for invoker. I was asking the problem on many forums and couldn't get help.

### Code

lib.rs

```rs
mod event;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::event::*;
    fn test(mut x: i32,y: i32, entries: &[&dyn Fn(i32)]) -> i32 {
        for entry in entries {
            x *= 3;
            (entry)(x);
        }
        x * y
    }
    fn invoker<'a>(entries: &'a [&'a dyn Fn(i32)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {
        move |y|test(1,y,&entries)
    }
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let mut event_test = EventKey::new(invoker);
        let test = &|x: i32| {
            println!("Hello {}", x);
        };
        event_test.on_event(test);
        event_test.on_event(test);
        event_test.on_event(test);
        let result = event_test.invoke()(10);
        assert_eq!(result, 270);
    }
}
```

event.rs

```rs
/// Event file
/// I - invoker type
/// R - additional return type
/// C - Callback arguments
/// Please know that this applies to everything in this file

pub struct EventKey<I, C> {
    invoker: I,
    callbacks: Vec<C>
}

impl<I,C,R> EventKey<I,C>
where I: Fn (&[C]) -> R
{
    pub fn new(invoker: I) -> EventKey<I, C> {
        EventKey {
            invoker,
            callbacks: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn on_event(&mut self, callback: C) {
        self.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    pub fn invoke(&self) -> R {
        (self.invoker)(&self.callbacks)
    }
}
```

### The errors

1. Without lifetimes

```rs
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Fn(i32) -> i32` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:14:9
   |
13 |     fn invoker(entries: &[&dyn Fn(i32)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
   |                         --------------- hidden type `[closure@src/lib.rs:14:9: 14:17]` captures the anonymous lifetime defined here
14 |         move |y|test(1,y,&entries)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: to declare that `impl Fn(i32) -> i32` captures `'_`, you can introduce a named lifetime parameter `'a`
   |
13 |     fn invoker<'a>(entries: &'a [&'a dyn Fn(i32)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a  {
   |               ++++           ++   ++                                      ++++
```

2. With lifetimes

```rs
error[E0599]: the method `on_event` exists for struct `EventKey<for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}, &dyn Fn(i32)>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:22:20
   |
22 |         event_test.on_event(test);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: src/event.rs:7:1
   |
7  | pub struct EventKey<I, C> {
   | ------------------------- method `on_event` not found for this struct
   |
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker} as FnOnce<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>>::Output = _`
      `for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}: Fn<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>`
  --> src/event.rs:13:10
   |
12 | impl<I,C,R> EventKey<I,C>
   |             -------------
13 | where I: Fn (&[C]) -> R
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |          |            |
   |          |            unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
   |          unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}: FnMut<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>`
           which is required by `for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}: Fn<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>`
           `for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}: FnOnce<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>`
           which is required by `for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a (dyn Fn(i32) + 'a)]) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {invoker}: Fn<(&[&dyn Fn(i32)],)>`
```

Comment: Your `test` function captures the parameter `entries` without specifying the lifetime of that parameter. Add lifetimes to your `test` function just like you added to your trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make sure that `test` in `it_works` is of the correct type:

```rust
let test: &dyn Fn(i32) = &|x| {
    println!("Hello {}", x);
};
```

You have to annotate the lifetimes in the implementation to match that of your usage:

```rust
impl<I, C> EventKey<I, C> {
    pub fn new(invoker: I) -> EventKey<I, C> {
        EventKey {
            invoker,
            callbacks: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn on_event(&mut self, callback: C) {
        self.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    pub fn invoke<'a, R>(&'a self) -> R
    where
        I: Fn(&'a [C]) -> R + 'a,
        R: 'a,
        C: 'a,
    {
        (self.invoker)(&self.callbacks)
    }
}
```

Note: After correctly annotating the lifetimes the compiler then complains that `R` is not constrained and rightfully so, to fix it I moved the bounds and type parameter to apply to the `invoke` method only.